# getting raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY' with django on production settings

Tags: python, django, keyerror

I've 2 separate settings files for production and development and a common base.py settings file 
**base.py**

```
SECRET_KEY = r"!@#$%^&123456"
```

**prod.py**

```
from .base import *
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

**manage.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings.dev")

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

When I enter this in terminal:

```
python manage.py shell --settings=entri.settings.prod
```

I get error:

```
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

Help me, I'm new to django and python

Comment: So, where are you setting the SECRET_KEY environment variable?

Comment: I think you are trying this locally, and don't have the SECRET_KEY setup in your environment. Set it using `export SECRET_KEY="somevalue"`, and then this should work fine.

Comment: @mu無 Yes, I'm running this locally. I set the `SECRET_KEY` in **base.py**. That file is imported into **prod.py**. Shouldn't that suffice?? What am I missing?

Comment: @mu無 Thank you, I figured it out, you were right. Thanks a lot for dumbing it down for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are trying this locally, and don't have the `SECRET_KEY` setup in your environment.

Set it using

```
export SECRET_KEY="somesecretvalue"
```

and then running `python manage.py shell --settings=entri.settings.prod` should work fine.

Comment: Hi, are you able to explain how to set a secret key within the environment, I am having issues with this exact problem and can't figure it out. Thank you

Comment: @CThomas You can ask a fresh question for that with the exact problem you are facing and someone from the community should hopefully answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I use os.getenv('SECRET_KEY'), instead of os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

```
print os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')    #returns None if KEY doesn't exist
print os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 0) #will return 0 if KEY doesn't exist
```

my python version is 2.7.12

Answer (score 0):

In Django while trying to secure/hide my secret_key, my problem was even after setting the secret_key using the set command on windows, I still got a 'Key must not be empty' error. I solved that by removing all the spaces before and after the assignment operator in the command. In your cmd, write

set SECRET_KEY="kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"

instead of

set SECRET_KEY = "kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk"