# Confusion regarding Django and SECRET_KEY

Tags: python, django

Recently finished my app and I am ready to deploy it but I don't understand how to set the application's SECRET_KEY. I'm trying to change my database from sqlite to postgresql, but I get the following error:

> raise KeyError(key) from None
> KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

**development.py**

```py
from nurs_course.settings.common import *

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', 'localhost']

SECRET_KEY = '9t*re^fdqd%-o_&zsu25(!@kcbk*k=6vebh(d*9r)+j8w%7ci1'

DEBUG = True
```

***production.py***

```py
from nurs_course.settings.common import *

DEBUG = False

SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

# SECURITY WARNING: update this when you have the production host
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', 'localhost']
```

`common.py` has all the other settings required. I use Windows OS w/ Powershell. I've been stuck on this for a bit and I am just unsure how to set the SECRET_KEY properly. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090391/getting-raise-keyerrorkey-keyerror-secret-key-with-django-on-production-set).

If you're using a virtual environment, you might want to activate it and run this code:

```
export SECRET_KEY='9t*re^fdqd%-o_&zsu25(!@kcbk*k=6vebh(d*9r)+j8w%7ci1'
```

After that run `python manage.py shell --settings=entri.settings.prod`

Comment: Where do I run this? Powershell does not recognize export as a cmd.

Comment: Figured out I needed to do `set` instead of export but I get the same exact error. Help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to export SECRET_KEY in the following way,

```py
export SECRET_KEY="somesecretvalue"
```

If you are using Python 2.x, try:

```py
os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
```

Comment: Do I run that in the Powershell terminal? It says export is not a recognized cmdlet

Comment: @waifuxszn, you can export the SECRET_KEY in the following way: os.environ["MY_DATA"] = "my_export"

Comment: how would I do that all in a Powershell terminal though?